# Share on LinkedIn button

Tags: php, html

I've found tons of examples to create share on linkedIn this site and others but I'm starting to learn that this approach isn't available anymore?

```
<?php

$obj_id = get_queried_object_id();
$actual_link = get_permalink( $obj_id );

$pageTitle = urlencode(get_the_title());
$pageUrl = urlencode(get_permalink());
?>

<a id="linkedIn"  href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php print($pageTitle); ?>">
```

It outputs as -

```
href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http://localhost:8888/identity-library/ungated-html/&amp;title=Three Questions with Senior Engineering Manager, Maggie Way"
```

But [it doesnt work](https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://localhost:8888/identity-library/ungated-html/&title=Three%20Questions%20with%20Senior%20Engineering%20Manager,%20Maggie%20Way%22)

Comment: why is url parameter http://localhost:8888/identity-library/ungated-html/&title=Three Questions with Senior Engineering Manager, Maggie Way" ? i do not think that may work

Comment: It's just my local environment. But on the live site doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

So, I just noticed, the URL you are trying to share starts with `http://localhost:8888...`.  That needs to be a real URL, that LinkedIn can see, for it to populate any information about it, or in fact, for LinkedIn to consider that URL worthwhile to share.  Try wikipedia.org, and it works.

But, then -- `&title=YourTitle` as a `GET` parameter ***is still broken***, and does not populate in the share preview display.  Here is the solution to that: for now, if you want the URL you are sharing on LinkedIn to have preview values for `title`, `image`, etc., is to use `og:` Open Graph tags, as defined in the [**Open Graph Protocol**](https://ogp.me/).

First, you'll want to update your URL...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

This URL fits the new **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

According to the documentation, these are the options you have available...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

Want to see that you're doing things right?  Check out the [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).

Still not sure?  I have coded up a demo website with 30 different social share services, and the share link for LinkedIn certainly works for me!  Check it out: [SortWords.com](https://www.sortwords.com).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something huge, OP is not asking about `og` properties. Also, the promotion of your site is largely arbitrary & would be considered by some as spam.

Comment: Hey, esqew, thanks for reaching out.  It's merely a demo link, I don't make money from it.  And the `og:` tags are now the only available way to populate a title/image preview in the LinkedIn share link, the way the OP was trying by appending `&title=...sometitle`.  Docs seem to support this, too!